# Stored Procedure : Invalid column index

Tags: java

(JAVA)I have a DBConnection class and a main class.
In DBConnection class, connection  to db made via constructor.

```
public class DBConnection {

private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:PORT:TesttDb";
private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "est";
private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "est";
private Connection conn = null;

public DBConnection() {

try {
Class.forName(DEFAULT_DRIVER);
String url = DEFAULT_URL;
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user", DEFAULT_USERNAME);
props.setProperty("password", DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
} 
catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
System.out.println(ex);
}
}


 public ResultSet getDetails(int id) throws SQLException
    {
        CallableStatement cs;
        cs=conn.prepareCall("{call GET_DETAILS(?,?,?,?)}");
        cs.setInt(1, id);
        cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(4, Types.INTEGER);
        ResultSet rs=cs.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(cs.getObject(1));

        return rs;

    }
```

and my main class is

```
public class DBMain {

public static void main(String arg[]) {
try {
DBConnection dBConnection = new DBConnection();
CallableStatement cs=dBConnection.getDetails(1);
System.out.println(cs.getObject(1));
} catch (Exception ex) {
System.out.println(ex);
}
}
}
```

here connection is ok..

my stored procedure is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_DETAILS
(
P_ID IN SAMPLE.ID%TYPE,
P_NAME OUT SAMPLE.NAME%TYPE,
P_ADDRESS OUT SAMPLE.ADDRESS%TYPE,
P_AGE OUT SAMPLE.AGE%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
NAME,ADDRESS,AGE INTO P_NAME,P_ADDRESS,P_AGE
FROM SAMPLE
WHERE SAMPLE.ID=P_ID;
END;
/
```

my database table is

```
SQL> desc sample
 Name                            Null?    Type
 ------------------------------- -------- ----
 ID                              NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 NAME                            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20
 ADDRESS                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20
 AGE                             NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
```

I have one row in table with `id=1`

but after executing the main method. I am getting an exception

```
run:
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

any idea or help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: cs.getString(1); this seem be wrong try to omit it and then check your code

Comment: First of all keep good name convention, You have gave `executeQuery` name to `Resultset` Object i.e. not proper one and I think you will have to return `Resultset` not `Callable` statement in method.

Comment: And *where* are you getting the exception? Please show the full stack trace. It would help if you could indent your code to make it easier to reader, too.

Comment: public ResultSet getDetails(int id) throws SQLException
    {
        CallableStatement cs;
        cs=conn.prepareCall("{call GET_DETAILS(?,?,?,?)}");
        cs.setInt(1, id);
        cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(4, Types.INTEGER);
        ResultSet rs=cs.executeQuery();
        return rs;
        
    }

Comment: but the same exception exists..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are registering the out parameter with index 2. How can u retrieve with `cs.getXXX(1)` ?
It must be `cs.getXXX(2)` after calling `cs.executeQuery()`

Answer (score 0):

Can u try

```
 cs.executeUpdate();
cs.getString(1);
```